# GCRduino shows up briefly in the IDE and then disappears

Tags: hardware

I have two UNO boards from a few years ago. They look the same as far as chip placement goes.

I can plug both in and get flashing lights on them, and when I hit the reset (2x the on-off) button, they both make the same LED "noises".  Since the LEDs on the non-detected board flash the same start-up sequence as a board that is detected, I assume both boards are working.

One of them has "UNO" printed on the circuit board and the other has "GCRduino Rev 1.0" printed on the circuit board. (edited according the comments for clarification)

I'm using Linux Mint 21 and Arduino IDE 2.0.3.

On hardinfo (the linux program), both of them are listed in Devices->USB Devices as "QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter."

The one that has UNO printed on the board is detected and I can load software onto it. The one that say GCRduino is not detected by the IDE and no new entry shows up in /dev.

The GCRduino is detected for a split second and then disappears again.  check this video: http://100wires.com/arduino.mp4

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how these SE sites work. -- Are you sure that the GCRduino has a compatible boot loader? Please [edit] your question and tell us what your research on the device has revealed so far.

Comment: Arduino clones that use the CH34x chips generally do not show list the IDE or hardware lists as being a particular board, because the necessary information to positively identify them is not provided by the CH34x chip.
So, I'm skeptical that _"one says UNO is detected"_ and _"both of them are listed as...CH340..."._ are both true. Make sure the information in your question is correct.

Comment: @timemage Presumably "_says UNO_" means that the word "UNO" is printed somewhere on its circuit board. ;-) Therefore I don't think the OP wanted to say that Linux reports "UNO". Technical terms are difficult for casual users.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stumbling on the grammar I guess. Anyway, I take your point.

Comment: i've updated the post for accuracy.

Comment: did you try it on a different computer?

Comment: No.  same computer.  see my answer.

Comment: so yes I see you answer. and you didn't try it on a different computer before asking a question here. and the problem is with the computer not with the arduino

Comment: yes, that's why i mentioned the LED noises, although i didn't specify that the noises seem to indicate that it's working.  i've updated my question again for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with dmesg.  When I insert the card and it shows up very briefly, it gets kicked by another device:

```
[  167.032321] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input25
[  172.660038] usb 3-3: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  172.809032] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.62
[  172.809038] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  172.809041] usb 3-3: Product: USB2.0-Serial
[  172.810938] ch341 3-3:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
[  172.811372] usb 3-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[  173.349731] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input26
[  173.655257] usb 3-3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
[  173.656203] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[  173.656275] ch341 3-3:1.0: device disconnected
```

I can see the device on lsusb:

Bus 003 Device 008: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter

That same device serial number is listed in

```
grep 1a86 /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules
ENV{PRODUCT}=="1a86/7523/*", ENV{BRLTTY_BRAILLE_DRIVER}="bm", GOTO="brltty_usb_run"
```

So when it connects, it gets kicked off by it being detected as another device.

So I just comment out that line in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/85-brltty.rules, restart, and the board can now be detected.

Comment: Seems to be the same as [this issue](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/88726/arduino-uno-r3-not-recognized-by-arduino-ide-on-ubuntu-21-04/90273#90273).

Comment: It is, thanks.  I've updated my question with more keywords/descriptions so maybe other's can more easily find the problem.